# rawTransactionManager.sendRawTransaction throwing Can't get transaction receipt error

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, quorum

Below is my code snippet to send transaction

```
var router= require('express').Router();

var request = require('request');


var config = require('../config/config')

const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3( new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:22000"));
const quorumjs = require("quorum-js");
//const tessera =  quorumjs.encalves.Tessera(web3, "http://localhost:9081", "http://localhost:9081");
const enclaveOptions = {
    privateUrl: "http://localhost:9081" // Tessera ThirdParty server url, use ipcPath if using Constellation
  };
  const accAddress = "ed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d";
const account1 = '0xed9d02e382b34818e88B88a309c7fe71E65f419d'
const signAcct = web3.eth.accounts.decrypt({"address":account1,
"crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","ciphertext":"4e77046ba3f699e744acb4a89c36a3ea1158a1bd90a076d36675f4c883864377",
"cipherparams":{"iv":"a8932af2a3c0225ee8e872bc0e462c11"},"kdf":"scrypt",
"kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"n":262144,"p":1,"r":8,"salt":"8ca49552b3e92f79c51f2cd3d38dfc723412c212e702bd337a3724e8937aff0f"},
"mac":"6d1354fef5aa0418389b1a5d1f5ee0050d7273292a1171c51fd02f9ecff55264"},"id":"a65d1ac3-db7e-445d-a1cc-b6c5eeaa05e0","version":3}, '');
const rawTransactionManager = quorumjs.RawTransactionManager(web3, enclaveOptions);
var contract= new  web3.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);

router.post('/addAsset', function(req, res) {

    var x= req.body.x;
    console.log ('x: ',x);
    var y= req.body.y;
    console.log ('y: ',y);
    const data = contract.methods.addAsset(assetId,JSON.stringify(assetMetadata)).encodeABI();
  //  console.log ('data: ',data);
  var bytecode = "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";
    rawTransactionManager.sendRawTransaction({gasPrice: 0, gasLimit: 4300000, to: contractAddress, value: 0, 
        data: bytecode, from: signAcct,
     isPrivate: true, privateFrom: "BULeR8JyUWhiuuCMU/HLA0Q5pzkYT+cHII3ZKBey3Bo=",
     privateFor: ["ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc="], nonce:13});
    
     

 
});
```

I am getting the error below :

> (node:19638) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't get
> transaction receipt
> at web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt.then.txReceipt (/home/rkomaturi/node_modules/quorum-js/lib/enclave/generic.js:68:13)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: Hi , Any help please